How to add ALIAS record for CloudDNS in GCP
As stated in GCPs documentation:

You can configure alias records by using the gcloud CLI or the Cloud
DNS API. You cannot configure alias records by using the Google Cloud
console.

There are no example's online how to do this so I tried the following:
gcloud dns --project=my-project record-sets update .example.com. --type="ALIAS" --zone="example-com" --rrdatas="another.website.net." --ttl="300"

But get error:
ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnknownRdatatype): DNS resource record type is unknown.


Which version of the CLI are you using? This feature was added in version 398. You must also specify the beta flag (gcloud beta dns record-sets update ...) You have a period in front of the host name which I think is incorrect and is not required.

Note: If your target implements HTTPS (SSL certificates) or TLS then the target site must have CN/SAN entries for both DNS names otherwise web browsers will refuse to connect and TLS applications will report TLS certificate errors. I would not use your strategy of an ALIAS record for web/HTTP sites. Instead, use HTTP redirects and not DNS. If your real issue is a Layer 7 problem, do not try to solve it with DNS which knows nothing about HTTP/TLS/SSL.
